# Ubuntu 20.04.1 stuck at "keyboard = person"-screen in VirtualBox 6.0

Tags: boot, virtualbox

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 20.04.1 under VirtualBox 6.0 in Windows 10, Dell XPS laptop. Every time I try to boot the Ubuntu iso-file on VirtualBox I get stuck at the same screen and nothing happens afterwards. Any ideas what is causing this and what should I do about it?

Here is a screenshot of the stuck screen:

[image]

Nothing happens after this screen shows up. Here is some information about my system:

```
Host: Windows 10 Enterprise, 64-bit, Intel i7, 32GB RAM, AMD Radeon Pro WX 3200
Ubuntu: 20.04.1 Focal Fossa
Ubuntu hash checked: YES 
VirtualBox version: 6.0
VirtualBox -> System -> Base memory: around 22GB 
VirtualBox -> Display -> Video memory: 128MB
VirtualBox -> System -> Processors: 4
VirtualBox -> System -> Acceleration -> Enable VT-x/AMD-V, Enable Nested Paging: both YES
VirtualBox -> Display -> Graphics controller: VMSVGA
VirtualBox -> Display -> Enable 3D acceleration: NO
ISO-file name: ubuntu-20.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso
Hyper-V disabled: YES
```

UPDATE: I think I resolved this but I will wait until I have everything working. The solution was: Disable Windows Credential Guard.

Answer (score 0):

I got it resolved. If you use Windows enterprise edition you have to disable Windows credential guard.